# check if the aro has permission for a certain aco

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I have ACL layer setup in my application. But I need to print out a report for management that what acos are allowed by which aro (users only in this case); I looked into aco tables and in aco_aro table but it doesnt make any sense to me to generate a simple report that which aco can be access by which aro for example.

So how do I generate that, so called report? Currently you get permission denied message if you dont have access to certain acos but thats about it. I would have to go one by one to see all those and compare them to users which is very daunting manual task and extremely difficult if not impossible! So I was wondering if you guys use some audit or something for that.

**EDIT**

**since no one responded to this question, I will tune down my requirements.How can  upon login  of a user  can I get  what acos the user has permissions to?. Can someone tell me how I check that. thanks**

** TRIED THIS**

```
 if ($this->Auth->login()) {
             debug($this->Acl->check( 'User', 'Posts', $action = '*'));
```

but get this

```
Warning (512): DbAcl::check() - Failed ARO/ACO node lookup in permissions check.  Node references:
Aro: User
Aco: Posts [CORE/Cake/Controller/Component/Acl/DbAcl.php, line 79]
/app/Controller/UsersController.php (line 20)
false
```

Comment: tried $this->Acl->view($id) but that doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested by such a component. I'm pretty sure part of the job could be done differently but my knowledge of the Acl component is not good enough for that.

```
<?php
class AclToolsComponent extends Object {

    var $controller = null;
    var $components = array('Acl');

    function initialize(&$controller, $settings = array()) {
        $this->controller = $controller;
    }

    function getUserPermissions($userId) {
        if (!isset($this->controller->User)) {
            $this->controller->loadModel('User');
        }
        $this->controller->User->id = $userId;
        $aro_node = $this->controller->Acl->Aro->node($this->controller->User);
        $aliases = $this->getAcoAliases();
        $aros = $this->controller->Acl->Aro->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Aro.id' => $aro_node[0]['Aro']['id'],
            ),
        ));

        $permissions = array();
        foreach ($aros['Aco'] as $aco) {
            $acl_cmd = ($aco['Permission']['_create'] == 1)?'allow':'deny';
            $permissions[] = $acl_cmd.' '.$aliases[$aco['id']];
        }

        return $permissions;
    }

    function getAcoAliases() {
        $aliases = array();
        $acos = $this->controller->Acl->Aco->find('threaded', array(
            'contain' => array()
        ));

        $this->fillAliases($aliases, $acos, '');

        return $aliases;
    }

    private function fillAliases(&$aliases, $acos, $name) {
        foreach ($acos as $aco) {
            $sep = (!empty($name))?'/':'';
            $new_name = $name.$sep.$aco['Aco']['alias'];
            $aliases[$aco['Aco']['id']] = $new_name;
            if (!empty($aco['children'])) {
                $this->fillAliases($aliases, $aco['children'], $new_name);
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

From a controller, you might then use the following code to get an idea of how it works

```
$perm = $this->AclTools->getUserPermissions($userId);
debug($perm);
```

It will display the aco that are specifically granted or denied to a user. It means that if you grant access to the full Posts controller to someone, you will get only

```
allow controllers/Posts
```

and not

```
allow controllers/Posts
allow controllers/Posts/add
allow controllers/Posts/edit
...
```

Comment: thank you for the component. I added this component under the /controllers/component/AclToolsComponent.php but it gives me these errors 
Warning (2): call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'AclToolsComponent' does not have a method 'startup' [CORE/Cake/Utility/ObjectCollection.php, line 130]

Comment: in cakePHP 2, the component needs to extend Component and not Object. I guess it might be the problem.

Comment: no I have taken the code out and used it directly in the controller but still it gives the null array. is it working for you?

Comment: yes it works. Are you sure the user you are working on is granted or denied specific acos (i mean directly and not through a group he would belong to for example). Try debug($aros) to see if what you get is correct.

Comment: changing object to component changed the errors. Now it says AclNode::node() - cant find node Aro node identified by "Array ( [Aro0.model] < User [Aro0.foreign_key] > ) "

Comment: I think issue is here $this->Acl->Aro->node($this->User) as node doesnt exist in cake 2.0

Comment: node() does exist. I just checked the Api (http://api20.cakephp.org/view_source/acl-node#line-60). Try node(array('model' => 'User', 'foreign_key' => $userId)) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The best and clean approach is well documented [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-cakephps-access-control-lists--net-13457)